# reading a text file and sort it in a new file

Tags: c, file, sorting

I have a school assignment in which we have to read a text file, sort the words by alphabetical order and write the result into a new text file.

I've already got a program that can read the file and print it on the screen and a different program to sort words which you have to type in. Now I'm trying to merge these two programs, so that the data which been read out of the file will be put into the sorting program.

The program that we use to make the code is called CodeBlocks. Below are the two programs. I hope that you can give me advice and an example how to fix this because I tried everything I know but couldn't get it working.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define MAX_NUMBER_WORDS 100
char* ReadFile(char *filename)
{
    char *buffer = NULL;
    int string_size, read_size;
    FILE *handler = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (handler)
    {
        //seek the last byte of the file
        fseek(handler, 0, SEEK_END);
        //offset from the first to the last byte, or in other words, filesize
        string_size = ftell(handler);
        //go back to the start of the file
        rewind(handler);

        //allocate a string that can hold it all
        buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (string_size + 1));
        //read it all in one operation
        read_size = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), string_size, handler);
        //fread doesnt set it so put a \0 in the last position
        //and buffer is now officialy a string
        buffer[string_size] = '\0';

        if (string_size != read_size)
        {
            //something went wrong, throw away the memory and set
            //the buffer to NULL
            free(buffer);
            buffer = NULL;
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}

int numberOfWordsInDict(char **dict)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_WORDS; i++)
    {
        if (dict[i] == NULL)
            return i;
    }
    return MAX_NUMBER_WORDS;
}

void printDict(char **dict)
{
    int i;
    printf("Dictionary:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfWordsInDict(dict); i++)
        printf("- %s\n", dict[i]);
    if (numberOfWordsInDict(dict) == 0)
        printf("The dictionary is empty.\n");
}


void swapWords(char **dict, char *word, char *word2)
{
    int i, p1 = -1, p2 = -1;
    char *tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfWordsInDict(dict); i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(dict[i], word) == 0)
            p1 = i;
        if (strcmp(dict[i], word2) == 0)
            p2 = i;
    }
    if (p1 != -1 && p2 != -1)
    {
        tmp = dict[p1];
        dict[p1] = dict[p2];
        dict[p2] = tmp;
    }
}

void sortDict(char **dict)
{
    int swap;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        swap = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < numberOfWordsInDict(dict) - 1; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(dict[i], dict[i + 1]) > 0)
            {
                swapWords(dict, dict[i], dict[i + 1]);
                swap = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (swap == 1);
}

void splitSentenceToWords(char **words, char *sentence)
{
    int p1 = 0, p2 = 0;
    int nrwords = 0;
    char *word;
    while (sentence[p2] != '\0')
    {
        if (isspace(sentence[p2]) && p1 != p2)
        {
            word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(p2 - p1 + 1));
            words[nrwords] = word;
            strncpy(words[nrwords], &sentence[p1], p2 - p1);
            words[nrwords][p2 - p1] = '\0';
            nrwords++;
            p1 = p2 + 1;
            p2 = p1;
        }
        else
        {
            p2++;
        }
    }
    if (p1 != p2)
    {
        word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(p2 - p1 + 1));
        words[nrwords] = word;
        strncpy(words[nrwords], &sentence[p1], p2 - p1);
        words[nrwords][p2 - p1] = '\0';
        nrwords++;
        p1 = p2 + 1;
        p2 = p1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char sentence[1024];
    char *dict[MAX_NUMBER_WORDS] = {};
    char *words[MAX_NUMBER_WORDS] = {};
    char *string = ReadFile("test.txt");
    if (string)
    {
        puts(string);
        free(string);
    }
    //printf("Type een zin in: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &sentence);
    splitSentenceToWords(words, &sentence);
    printDict(words);
    printf("Words has been sorted\n");
    sortDict(words);
    printDict(words);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler. Please learn [ask], provide a [mcve] and a specific problem. SO is no tutoring service.

Comment: And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends (or `void *` in general) in C!

Comment: Isn't `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` a MSVC control?

Comment: TL;DR what specifically is the problem?

Comment: There is no need to allocate `string_size + 1`, `string_size` will do, you are reading an entire file, not a string. (in other words, a file is not *nul-terminated*)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. The problem is that after your read in your file, you are not using the input to build your word list. Instead of;

```
splitSentenceToWords(words, &sentence);
```

try:

```
splitSentenceToWords(words, &string);
```

Delete
`free(string)`

This will get you started. You will have to clean this up when you understand it a bit better.

Comment: i already have tried to replace &sentence by &string but i didn't deleted free(string). i tried what you said but then the output from the dictionary won't give me the words that i have put in the test file. it just give some symbols.

Comment: for some reason the text file is read correctly and put on the screen but when i put the text from the file in the sorting programm it wont read it correct so that is why i get random symbols

Comment: Try printing out your results as each word is extracted in the split function.